# Contour line at specific value is not getting drawn

Tags: matlab, contour

Using the following matrices

```
test1 =
[-0.200000000000000 -0.180000000000000  -0.160000000000000  -0.140000000000000  -0.120000000000000;
 -0.200000000000000 -0.180000000000000  -0.160000000000000  -0.140000000000000  -0.120000000000000];

test2 = 
[0.0153000000000000 0.0183000000000000  0.0212000000000000  0.0247000000000000  0.0281000000000000;
 0.0206000000000000 0.0227000000000000  0.0247000000000000  0.0273000000000000  0.0306000000000000];

test3 = 
[-2 -2  -2  -2  -2;
[-1 -1  -1  -1  -1];
```

(minified) I want to plot some contour lines like

```
figure
contour(test1,test2,test3,[value1, value2, ...],'ShowText','on');
```

However, the contour line for `-2` is not being plotted, even when doing

```
figure
contour(test1,test2,test3,[-2 -2],'ShowText','on');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 2 ideas:

1) `,` is a separator, not the difference between decimal and integer places. your data is `0` and then `200000000000000`. Probably not what you wanted. Replace those comas by `.`.

2) Once you have that, it should almost work. However, it doesnt work with `-2` because that is on the limits, there is no boundary of `-2` with something else. Try `-1.5` for example, to see it working.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer: 1) Did not notice that copy paste changed the decimal point to a comma. 2) Why does it work then for `-1`?

Comment: @VGD its boundary behavior, probably just numerical precission.... If you are interested in the -2, put the level at -1.999 and change the label of the contour

Comment: Doing `contour(..., [-1.999 -1.999],...)`does not work either.